# Setting an h1 style to the equivalent of font-size:none

Tags: html, css

I have sentences whose font size is determined by the class assigned.  For example

```
.font24{font-size:24px;}
```

Now I want to place  one of these sentences inside of  h1 tags, just so Google will see some structure and realize that this is something important it needs to index. But I don't want  the default h1 style to be applied to the sentence, which would override the .font24 class style.  So it looks like I need to define a new h1 style, but what do I put there to cancel the font size already being applied by the previous h1 declaration?  There doesn't seem to be a font-size:none like there is a text-decoration:none.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the correct way to hide the <h1> tag and not be banned from Google?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239202/whats-the-correct-way-to-hide-the-h1-tag-and-not-be-banned-from-google)

Comment: this is not what CSS is meant for...

Comment: As mentioned, there is no `font-size: none`, yet the title asks for an equivalent for it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO.

Comment: The question referenced - What's the correct way to hide the <h1> tag and not be banned from Google? - is nothing like my question.  I don't want to hide the h1 tag.  I just want to override the browser default format for it. Second, the question is about styling an h1 element. Just because Google uses h1 elements to index the page doesn't mean the question is about SEO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could resolve this by applying following css:

```
h1{
  font-size: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin:0;
}
.font24 {
  font-size:24px;
}
```

with HTML like this:

```
<h1 class="font24">This is my example example</h1>
```

Check the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tralala/p8eh2rfd/4/

Comment: What do you mean, "make h1 invisible"?  Will Google see it?  That's all I care  about.

Comment: Check the fiddle. Is that what you meant?

Comment: And yes, the text is still there, but applied styling changes its font to 0 size - this only applies to h1 tag used with no additional class which will not be your case anyway.

Comment: Ok.  Got it!  By the way, the new style for h1 needs to also include a margin:0 to keep all the browser styling for it quiet.  - Thanks.

Comment: Hey, thank you ;) I did not notice it at first. I also added it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use zero instead:

```
.font24{font-size:0px;}
```

Comment: Please explain briefly how your answer works to make it more useful for readers.

Comment: If it doesn't display the text how is Google going to index it?

Comment: google will go through the code not what displayed in webpage.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is using `visibility:hidden;`

You can create another class to be added to the current .font24

For instance create a new class called .hidden and combine it to the current:

**EXAMPLE**

```
.font24.hidden{visibility:hidden;}
```